# error while xcrun vtool for creating framework supporting arm64 simulator

Tags: xcode, arm64, xcframework

Project structure looks like
ProjectFolder/frameworkfolder/GoogleMaps.xcframework

Should i will be running below command to generate xcframework supporting arm64 for simulator in projectfolder or inside framework folder?

```
xcrun vtool -arch arm64 -show GoogleMaps.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps
```

on running this command i am getting error :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/vtool error: GoogleMaps.xcframework: can't read file: Is a directory
```